# MongoDB find() returns nothing

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to query my database from the mongodb shell to retrieve all the entries. Still, my find() method returns nothing.

This is the mongoose model that I am using:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var ArticleSchema = new Schema({
    title: String,
    content: String,
    author: { type: String, default: 'Vlad'},
    postDate: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
});

ArticleSchema.methods.formatTitle = function() {
    var link = this.title.replace(/\s/g, '-');
    return '/article/' + link;
};

ArticleSchema.methods.snapshot = function() {
    var snapshot = this.content.substring(0, 500);
    return snapshot;
};

module.exports = mongoose.model('Article', ArticleSchema);
```

When loading my Express.js application in the browser, I have no issues displaying all the articles that I have added using my API. Still, I just want to go inside the mongo shell and query them. I have used the following query:

```
// blog is the database name (mongodb://localhost:27017/blog)
db.blog.find()
```

I get an empty string in return, basically a new line in the console.

Comment: You can always use `db.getCollectionNames()` from the mongodb console to see what exists for a single database.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your answer is right there, in the question:

```
// blog is the database name (mongodb://localhost:27017/blog)
db.blog.find()
```

So `db` *already* refers to correct database. Instead of `blog`, put collection name, not db name.

```
db.articles.find()
```

Comment: I see. So, whenever I have a model called Model, mongodb automatically generates a collection (toLowerCase() + 's'), right? This is what I was missing :D

Comment: More likely, mongoose creates these collections upon first insertion. BTW, you can see all available collections by running this in the shell: `show collections`.

Answer (score 5):

Mongo shell will connect when started to the test database, you will need to change the database and then execute the find on your collection :

```
use blog
db.articles.find()
```

Comment: `use` statement is not necessary if database name is contained in the url

Comment: If you change the name of your first database, mongodb will continue to show you the name of the old database in the login url. Thus, the use allows to switch (or change manually in the url)

Answer (score 2):

First you choose the db, then you find **on the collection**.

```
use blog
db.articles.find()
```

Comment: I have used the use blog query before trying to use find()

Comment: have you used `db.articles.find()`? In the question it says "db.blog".

Comment: This is what I was looking for, as Sergio stated in his answer as well :D Thank you for the quick response!

Comment: use statement is not necessary if database name is contained in the connection string